# Doctrine Data Type (use Factory)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i want to implement a new doctrine data type (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html).

I have implemented an Country Service which loads country data via adapter from any library. Know i have the following implementation:

```
<?php
     interface CountryInterface;

     interface Address
     {
         public function setCountry(CountryInterface $country);
         public function getCountry() : CountryInterface;
     }
?>
```

So, what I want to do is - make a `CountryType` which converts the `Country` Object to an specific string value (used field will be set via `OptionClass`, ex.: Alpha2, Alpha3, IsoNumber).

My problem is, doctrine only allows data types mapping via classname, so I can't implement an factory to load all needed dependencies.

I hope this is understandable.

regards

Comment: Are you using Doctrine 2 ORM or just DBAL?

Comment: hi, at the moment i use doctrine 2 ORM, but in the future i will also support doctrine 2 ODM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to register your custom DBAL type for country extending the `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type` class:

```
<?php

namespace Application\DBAL\Types;

use Application\Resource\Country;
use Application\Service\CountryService;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use InvalidArgumentException;

class CountryType extends Type
{
    const NAME = 'country';

    /**
     * Country service
     */
    protected $countryService;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getDoctrineTypeMapping('text');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if($value === null){
            return null;
        }

        if ($value instanceof Country) {
            return (string) $value;
        }

        throw ConversionException::conversionFailed($value, self::NAME);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if($value === null){
            return null;
        }

        $country = $this->countryService->getCountry($value);
        if( ! $country instanceof Country ){
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailed($value, self::NAME);
        }

        return $country;
    }

    /**
     * Set country service
     *
     * @var CountryService $service
     */
    public function setCountryService ($service){
        $this->countryService = $service;
    }
}
```

This type needs to implement four methods `getName`, `getSQLDeclaration`, `convertToDatabaseValue` and `convertToPHPValue`.

- Thre first one returns the name for the type
- The second one is for the type declaration in the (SQL) database (I used `text` in the example, but you can also use integer or any other valid doctrine database type).
- The third method converts your country object to a database value (so in this case a text value).
- The last method does the opposite; it converts the text value from the database. In this case I just instantiate the Country class and pass the database value to the constructor. You need to add your custom logic inside your class constructor.

In my example I assume that `null` values are also allowed.

A simple version of your Country class could look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Resource;

class Country{

    protected $value;

    /**
     * Magic stringify to cast country object to a string
     */
    public function __toString(){
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor method
     */
    public function construct($value){
        $this->value = $value
        // set other properties...
    }

    // setters and getters...
}
```

It is up to you whether value should be `alpha2`/`alpha3`/`country_name` or whatever you want visible in the database. You should somehow also populate the other country with the other properties in the constructor method. I leave this part up to you.

Now you need to register your custom country type so doctrine will use it:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    //...
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            Application\DBAL\Types\CountryType::NAME =>  Application\DBAL\Types\CountryType::class,
        )
    )
)
```

And you can set your service on bootstrap in your application `Module.php` file:

```
/**
 * @param EventInterface|MvcEvent $event
 * @return void
 */
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
{
    $application    = $event->getApplication();
    $eventManager   = $application->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_BOOTSTRAP, array($this, 'initializeCountryType');
}

/**
 * @param MvcEvent $event
 */
public function initializeCountryType(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application    = $event->getApplication();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();

    //get your country service from service manager
    $countryService = $serviceManager->getCountryService();

    $countryType = \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getType('country');
    $countryType->setCountryService($countryService);
}
```

Now you can use your country type in any entity definition as follows:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="country", nullable=true)
 */
protected $country;
```

Read more on how to map custom DBAL types in the [Doctrine2 documentation chapter **Custom Mapping Types**](http://doctrine2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html)